# Accessing props in React constructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, react-props

I have a problem when I try to access parent's props value in the child class.

I am trying to initialize the child props with the parent's props.

But the following code shows me empty string of *value*.

```
export default class Child extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: props.value };
}
...
```

In other class I call this Child as follows:

```
const issue = this.state.issue;
...
<Child value={issue.number} />
...
```

I checked the number value before Child class is constructed (it shows me correct values), while it is construced, the value becomes empty..

For test, I used primitive number value, and it works.

Seems like some kind of link to issue.number is disconnected when Child is contructed.

Any clue?

Comment: FYI, I made mistake on question, value must be number. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could easily happen. For example, `issue.number` becomes a number after AJAX re-rendering. In this case you have to do follow (in your parent component):

```
render() {
  const issue = this.state.issue


  if (issue.number) {
    return <Child value={issue.number} />
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes I can follow your logic. In my case I load data in componentDidMount().

Comment: Accept answer this case :D

Comment: I handle such cases either using && operator or ternary operator. {issue.number && issue.number>0 && <Child value={issue.number} />} or {issue.number && issue.number >0 ? <Child value={issue.number} />: null}

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I just figured it out.

It is related to Lifecycle.

The number value is not loaded when I render Child.

So, I need to figure it out how to update the number in Child with my intention.

Comment: Use conditional to call child component if your issue.number is integer then do like {issue.number && issue.number > 0 && <Child value={issue.number} />} to get value in child component. This also avoid issue like issue.number is undefined

Comment: Ah, I found out that I don't even need the initialization, anyway the props value will be updated automatically eventually.

Comment: I didn’t get that and it’s confusing

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. My question lacks many information. In my case, the number is updated (setState) when componentDidMount() in parent class. So when I need issue.number in Child class ( it will be used in render() ), the props will be updated as the parent state is updated.